# I am building an app in flutter using vscode that is running well on iPhone simulator but when compile it for android emulator it gives the error

Tags: android, flutter, runtime-error

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':fluttertoast:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0.
> Required by:
> project :fluttertoast
> > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 17, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0:
> - gradle70JavadocElements
> - gradle70RuntimeElements
> - gradle70SourcesElements
> - javadocElements
> - runtimeElements
> - sourcesElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
> - Variant 'gradle70ApiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':fluttertoast' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':fluttertoast' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app level `build.gradle` (Android > app > build.gradle) scroll down to

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 33
}
```

The error is saying that from all the packages that you use in your project, you need atleast a minimum of SDK 33. Simply change that number, but keep in mind that this means older android phones will not be able to use your project.

Your other solution is to remove the library/package that requires SDK 33 and higher and find an alternative package, or downgrade it to use an older version.

Upgrading packages can sometimes require higher minimum Android SDK because owners maintain their package to be compatible with the latest Android release, which could incorporate new features, security, APIs, optimizations and other improvements that older android devices do not have. In this case when an old Android phone cannot read such features from the package, it gives the error that SDK version is not compatible.

I strongly suggest fixing the issue by upgrading Android SDK to 33, and those with older devices will need to buy a new phone to use your app. The higher SDK usually have improved performance, security and user experience.

You may find more information on which android devices belong to which SDK versions from this documentary:

https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platforms

Comment: The solution you suggested dear @Texv  worked for me well , One thing more I want to ask that if I upgrade all flutter packages then will it not support older phones too ?

Comment: yes, when package owners upgrade their version its to make it more compatible with the latest SDK to take advantage of the improved performance. I edited my answer to include more info